# maximum request lengths in node.js

Tags: node.js

For security, I'd like to set a maximum request length in my node.js application. (There are many security vulnerabilities which take advantage of web servers allowing unlimited request lengths).

Is this possible? Is there one already?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js HTTP Get URL Length limitation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32763165/node-js-http-get-url-length-limitation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you are referring to the data a client can send you through POST. If you are using Express, you can use the [limit](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/limit.js) middleware to achieve this: http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/middleware-limit.html

A short version of what's done there is:

```
req.on('data', function(chunk){
  received += chunk.length;
  if (received > bytes) req.destroy();
});
```

Comment: I'm also talking about GET—for example, see http://nikic.github.com/2011/12/28/Supercolliding-a-PHP-array.html for the kinds of issues that can come from accepting data from the client without limits.

Comment: It's easier for GET requests, for example you can create a middleware that only allows X variables maximum in a GET request. Example: using a regex you determine how many '&' symbols are in the request url. If the maximum number is exceeded you destroy the connection.