# node.js how to handle intentionally large (and bad) http requests

Tags: php, node.js

I'm working out on a few projects using node and each line of code that I write spans lots of ideas of how could someone destroy my node process.

Right now I'm thinking of this:

```
require('http').createServer(function(req, res)) {
    //DEAL WITH REQUEST HERE
  }.listen(port, net);
```

That's standard code for setting up a server and dealing with requests.

Let's say that I want to bring down that node process, I could send POST requests with loads of data on them and node.js would spend lots of time (and bandwith) on receiving all of them.

Is there a way to avoid this?

PHP Pros: How do you normally deal with this?

Is there a way to tell node or php (maybe apache) to just ignore requests from certain IPs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit the http request size.
Here is the middleware you can use.

https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/limit.js

http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/middleware-limit.html

P.S. Possibility duplication from [maximum request lengths in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696148/maximum-request-lengths-in-node-js)

For getting the IP address in node.js, you can try `request.connection.remoteAddress`.

Comment: particuarly on my case, it wouldn't help that much bc I'm writing an image uploader; I think I should provide at least 10MB and even with that an attacker could just send 100 10MB POSTS and there goes my 1GB bandwidth

Comment: If you provide image upload service, you should expect a large bandwidth would be used.

Of course, you can perform a IP filtering before letting the user to upload.